# Tracking how many people play my Unity game in which language?

Tags: unity, analytics

In my game the user can **change the language of the game** and I'd like to know **how many people play it in English, German, etc**.

I'm using **Unity**, so possibly I would like to implement in Unity Analytics.

I was thinking about adding **segments** for the languages, but in that case if a user tries all languages, the user will appear in all languages' segments. So it won't really provide that much info.

A possible solution:

- When the user changes language, we signal a database to decrease the old language's counter and increase the new language's counter.

But there must be an easier, built-in solution than this.

Comment: I think you're overstating how many languages one person tries. At most they will try one or two. You could even get a dimension for how many languages they have tried so you can see how accurate your language metric is

Comment: Well, you're right, it's good enough for a start.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you could do something like:

```
if (languages.language = languages.English)
{
    englishNumber += 1.0f;
}
```

for English, and for each player. This way, for each player with English as their language, `englishNumber` is increased by 1. Then take that number and set into a database that will be changed by all users, so nobody is left out. So if there are 58 players using "English", and each one adds `+1` to `englishNumber` (note that I mean they all add "+1" to the **same** `englishNumber` variable), then the result is that `englishNumber` would equal 58.

Comment: Can you recommend steps to implement this `englishNumber` using Unity Analytics?

Comment: Well, I'm not exactly a pro at Unity Analytics itself, I'm just saying as long as they know how to complete the Unity Analytics part, they could consider using the example I provided to add +1 for every player using the specified language.

Comment: @DMGregory does the Gem next to your name mean that you're a Moderator?

Comment: Since the question asks how to do this with Unity Analytics, it might be wise to research that API and test your suggestion before posting an answer. Chances are, it's not the "adding one to a variable inside an if" part that this user is having trouble with. And yes, that is what the gem means.

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought of in the original post as well, but I'd like to do it with analytics, so I don't have to have a backend just for this. :\ Sadly I couldn't figure out  how to make a similar behaviour work in analytics myself, so I've just sticked with Panda Pajama's answer at the original post.